# zfs snapshot -r for a single, simple dataset?

Tags: linux, freebsd, zfs

According to the man page `zfs snapshot -r` "recursively create[s] snapshots of all descendent datasets". As per [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/819-5461/ftyue.html), `dataset` is
`a generic name for the following ZFS components: clones, file systems, snapshots, and volumes`.

Now, if I have a single filesystem within a zpool and I create snapshots of it for backup purposes, should I use `zfs snapshot` or `zfs snapshot -r`? I think that in such case the `-r` option is meaningless as I don't have any nested filesystems and the only other nested datasets are the snapshots themselves, but I cannot find any confirmation for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assumption is correct. `-r` wouldn't have any effect in your case as there are no underlying file systems.